# Bestsubset selection method for categorical variable

Tags: r

[image]

My data contains two categorical variables geography with 3 levels(germany,france,spain) and gender with 2 levels(male,female). When i try to use the bestsubset selection, for some reason it will pull geographyGermany,and geographySpain as two predictors and GenderMale as one predictor as well.

So just wondering how can i make it remain as just geography and gender, without its levels popping out as a new variable?

Comment: I think you may wish to read up on the default behaviour of regression in R. This is how categorical variables are treated in linear regression. The intercept corresponds to the category that comes first alphabetically, in this case, females from France. If you want to see how the predictor geography contributes to the model, you can fit two models and compare them.

Comment: this actually is a classification problem, the outcome variable has 2 classes. Sorry, my not quite sorry, but i thought bestsubset selection actually go through all the potential models